# Can I build my meteor app to work with several different sets of packages using different mobile exports?

Tags: javascript, meteor, mobile

I am working on a fairly large webapp in Meteor. As advised my many experts, a good way to go for large apps is to split the different parts of the code in separate packages, like, e.g. [Telescope](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope). I designed everything with this objective in mind so I expect to be able to port everything to a package based "architecture".

Moreover, I plan to open source soon, so it should be also easier to maintain that way.

I have different types of users. Depending on it, I would like to build the app differently:

- One type of user is using the browser based version of the app. This user will get everything since I don't know how to selectively send some parts of the UI/client code (and I assume I can not)
- One type of mobile user will only have a subset of packages.
- Another type of mobile user will have another subset of packages.

So I have a browser full version (delivered by server) and two mobile app versions.

My understanding of mobile app exports is that I can compile different versions of my client code by removing/adding some specific packages before compiling, since a mobile app from meteor is a packaged version of all client side related code in an app.

Is that correct? Am I overlooking something?

Comment: The mobile version's html/js/css gets updated from the server automatically, so trying to build it with a different configuration initially might not stop it loading the same one as the web version.

Comment: Can you use `if (!Meteor.isCordova)` in the code to disable it on mobile?

Comment: @Alex028502 Meteor, in case of a mobile app, doesn't need to update client html/css/js, everything is already packed in the app. Using user roles, I can check that no useless data is sent either from publication or methods. `if (!Meteor.isCordova)` will be helpful in the browser version runned on mobile, if I plan to use mobile features. On the mobile app version, well, I already know I am on mobile. Thank you for the input however.

Comment: I think that that is just the initial version.  It will download a new version from the server as soon as it gets the chance, if I'm not mistaken.  You could probably stop it from doing this, but then you'll have to go through the app store with every update, which misses one of the big advantages of meteor.

Comment: Good point about the updates. I have no idea of how it works in a meteor mobile app context.

Comment: @Alex028502 have a look at this: http://meteorpatterns.com/Sewdn/project-builds

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking into this for a couple of days and things are changing in the Meteor world with the upcoming v1.3.

Regarding my question, yes, it could have been a way to go after meteor v1 if I believe [this article](http://meteorpatterns.com/Sewdn/project-builds)

However, [one of Meteor dev](http://info.meteor.com/blog/meteor-night-1.3-and-beyond) "announced" that Meteor will eventually drop the package system in favour of npm. One of the good things is that npm allows lazy (i.e. conditionnal & role based) loading of the different npm assets.

I will then look into this possibility. The one thing I miss would be an article or a tutorial showing what are the best practices when splitting a meteor app into npm packages. I assume that some, if not most of [the advises for package based architecture](https://meteor.hackpad.com/Building-Large-Apps-Tips-d8PQ848nLyE) are still standing.